# Generate 3 unique numbers from a set of numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm working on a project that makes three spaces of a game board different from the rest (+1,+2,-1) I need to add those values to a variable stored at the index of an ArrayList. 
I can find something to generate the numbers of the indices, but I don't know how to make sure that they are at unique indices. (It can't put all three of the values in one space)

How do I make three unique, random indices from in the range 0 to 16?

Thanks!

Comment: shows us some effort, and we will be more then happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Put all the possible numbers in a list - shuffle them and take the first three:

```
public class Test {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16));
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    System.out.println(numbers);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

printed

```
[5, 12, 4, 7, 2, 11, 14, 9, 3, 0, 15, 8, 1, 10, 13, 16, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to generate unique random number from the list of given numbers.

1. Generate a list of all possible values.
2. Shuffle it by using shuffle method from Collections `Collections.shuffle(list);`
3. Get item through iterating in each step.